# Number of ways arranging entries of a tuple - combinations or permutations

Tags: permutations, combinations

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ be an $n$-tuple where $n$ is even  In how many ways we can arrange such that exactly  half of the 
entries are even ?

My attempt is :  As we are talking about possible arrangements where order doesn't matter, so we will use combination, not permutation.
So for $n/2 = k$(say) even arrangements we have ${n \choose k}$ number of ways to arrange it. Is my solution right?  Kindly help me where I am going wrong.
Thanks for the help.

Let me explain with an example. Suppose $x=(x_1,\ldots x_6)$. now I want to arrange these $x′_i$s such that exactly at 3 positions I get even number. And yes, I am treating even and odd numbers as different categories. For ex. one way is that even numbers are at position number 1,2 and 3, another case may be at positions 1,2, and 4.....positions 2,4 and 6 is another way...... and so on.....

Comment: I don't understand the question. If the $x_i$ are given, then it's also given how many of them are even and how many are odd. How can you influence that by arranging them? Perhaps you mean "select entries" where it says "arrange"? But then we'd still have to know how many of the given ones are even and odd.

Comment: Sorry sir, I edited my question now. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Yes, I mean select entries.

Comment: No, I'm afraid it's still not clear. May I suggest that you write this in your native language and have someone translate it? If this is German or a major Romance language, I'll be happy to provide the translation.

Comment: Are you, perhaps, asking how many ways there are to arrange *n* distinct numbers of which exactly half are even, and whether we should use permutations or combinations for this ?

Comment: @trueblueanil: But how would their evenness bear on our options for arranging them?

Comment: @joriki: Presumably by treating even and odd numbers as separate categories, but OP has to respond ....

Comment: sorry for replying so late. Let me explain with an example. Suppose $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_6)$. now I want to arrange these $x_i's$ such that exactly at 3 positions I get even number. And yes, I am treating even and odd numbers as different categories.  For ex. one way is that even numbers are at position number 1,2 and 3, another case may be at positions 1,2, and 4.....positions 2,4 and 6 is another way...... and so on.....

Comment: Your use of "such that" is non-standard. "such that" means "with the outcome that". Since rearranging six numbers, three of which are even, will always result in getting an even number at exactly 3 positions, it makes no sense to say you want to arrange the numbers "such that" this happens. It seems that what you mean is to count the number of different resulting arrangements of the even numbers, disregarding the positions of the odd numbers.

Comment: I am sorry for my poor english. Yeah, you are right. I meant arrangements of even numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the *n-tuple* (with *n* even) has equal  numbers of odd and even *categories*

and you are confused as to whether combinations or permutations are to be used.

Actually, both amount to the same, e.g. for n = 6,

using combinations, you get **${6\choose 3} = \dfrac{6}{3!\cdot3!}$** and, as you know,

**$\dfrac{6}{3!\cdot3!}$** is also the formula for permutation where each category has multiple occurrences.

I hope this solves your dilemma !